# Exceptions thown when reading text inside email's body using javax.mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, exception

The email contents that I've received when subscribing to an email account are always multipart/alternative. So you cannot get the content with the method `message.getContent()`.

I've searched for solutions for this and got 2 ways to read the email content. But both of them throw an exception (the first one throws a MessagingException and the second throws a IOException).

Why are the exceptions thrown and can I fix it?

```
@Controller
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    public void listenMail() {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "/gmail-imap-idle-config.xml");
        DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);
        inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message) throws org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException {
                Message m = (Message) message.getPayload();

                try {
                    Object o = m.getContent();
                    if (o instanceof MimeMultipart) {
                        MimeMultipart mp = (MimeMultipart)o;
                        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {
                            MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) ((BodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(j));

                            // Only wanna get TEXT/PLAIN content
                            if(!mbp.getContentType().contains("TEXT/PLAIN")) {
                                logger.info("not text plain");
                                continue;
                            }

                            logger.info("First method: ");
                            System.out.println(mbp.getContent());

                            logger.info("Second method: ");
                            InputStream is = mbp.getInputStream();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                            String thisLine = reader.readLine();
                            while (thisLine != null && !thisLine.equals("")) {
                                lines.add(thisLine);
                                thisLine = reader.readLine();
                                System.out.println(thisLine);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.info("IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    logger.info("MessagingException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

1. This is MessagingException of the first way:

```
javax.mail.FolderClosedException
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:685)
    at com.example.demo.service.EmailService$1.handleMessage(EmailService.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter.lambda$prepareSendingTask$0(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:223)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

2. And this is the IOException of the second way:

```
com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException
at javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:114)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getInputStream(DataHandler.java:237)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getInputStream(MimeBodyPart.java:598)
    at com.example.demo.service.EmailService$1.handleMessage(EmailService.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter.lambda$prepareSendingTask$0(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:223)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: exceptions are there to communicate information to you. When you ask us to help with figuring out what they mean it would be helpful if you would show us the console output of the exceptions.

Comment: You will need to add the full stack traces of the exceptions, not just the `getMessage` string.

Comment: I've just added the stack trace of the exceptions. Sorry for my first post mistake!